# Method to get the style value from the object class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. I have created a class
2. Created a object to that class
3. Need to Create method to generate the legend style from the configuration.

Here is My Code Example,

```
ntt = {};
ntt.pgp = ntt.pgp || {};
ntt.pgp.StyleManager = function(opts){
    this.styleConfig = {
            site: {
                legendText: [{
                strokeWidth: 2,
                storkeColor: 'red',
                fillColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)',
                displayText: 'Polygon'
            }]
        }
    };
};

ntt.pgp.StyleManager.prototype.createLegend = function(layerId) {
// how to get the the style from the above object class.
```

I am very new to the JavaScript. Thanks

Comment: If you create an instance of `StyleManager` (with a `new StyleManager()`), then in `createLegend` the member `this.styleConfig` should be accessible.

Comment: is it like, var my legend =  this.styleConfig[layerId].legendText